# Python 3: how to check a method's default/ arguments

Tags: datetime, python-3.x

I know in python, you can use, say `dir(list)`to find out all the methods of `list`object, and then use `help(list.pop)` to look more of the details.

but when I came across `datetime`library, so there is a `timedelta`method which has the following attributes

> datetime.timedelta(days = 1)

```
datetime.timedelta(1)
```

> datetime.timedelta(hours = 1)

```
datetime.timedelta(0, 3600)
```

> datetime.timedelta(seconds = 1)

```
datetime.timedelta(0, 1)
```

but I looked all over the `help(datetime.timedelta)` documents, it only lists `days`, `seconds` in the library, there's nowhere to find `hours` attribute.

just in general, how do you find all the attributes of a method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you're better off bookmarking [the Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/) than using `help(some_function)`: `help()` shows you the function's `__doc__` attribute, which is usually a short reference to the function. Instead, if you'd gone to:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects

you would have found the `hours` parameter (and several others) that you were looking for.

Comment: If it's not in the standard library, and if the documentation is not on `readthedocs.org`, an alternate method is to just read the source code. (Unless it's an extension in C like numpy, in which case you will need to rely on the documentation.)

Comment: Thank you rmunn. I'm used to use the function in R which gives all the documents you need.